# How to add imageView into a framelayout programatically

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi in my xml file I have this a relativeLayout that contains textView and a frame layout :

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/id_send_EditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:hint="@string/enter_text"
            android:textColorHint="@color/com_facebook_button_background_color_disabled"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fl_pubCreate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </FrameLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

And I want to create an ImageView and add it programmatically into the frame layout.
How to do that.
Here is the riched method which gonna do the job :

```
 flayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);

private void mediaRecue() {
        if(Pub_media_type.equalsIgnoreCase("image/jpeg")){
            ImageView imgMedia = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            Picasso.with(this)
                    .load(Pub_media_uri)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.circular_progress_view)
                    .into(imgMedia);
            //How to add img into flayout

        }else if(Pub_media_type.equalsIgnoreCase("video/mp4")){
            VideoView videoView = new VideoView(getApplicationContext());
            //how to add Video into flayout
        }
    }
```

Comment: Simply call flayout.addView(imgMedia);

Comment: have you googled this question? It´s one of the basics how to add a view into a layout. You simply have to call `flayout.addView(imgMedia)` . The only thing to be aware of is to set the correct LayuotParams, this depends on how you want your image to appear..

Answer (score 0):

Simple add

```
flayout.addView(imgMedia);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
flayout.addView(imgMedia);
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.